# Change column order with jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

My code is like this : http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/ebRXw/805/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "responsive": true
    } );
} );
```

In [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/ebRXw/805/):

- Column 0 = Name
- Column 1 = Position
- Column 2 = Office

I want to change it to be like this without changing the HTML:

- Column 0 = Salary
- Column 1 = Start date
- Column 2 = Age

Comment: How about changing the HTML? Or do you want change the order without changing the HTML?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, Yes, I want change the order without changing the HTML

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, I need your help. You try to see here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33206742/server-side-datatables-with-ignited-datatables-library?noredirect=1#comment54233280_33206742). Does it modify the Ignited-Datatables Library?

Answer (score 7):

> **SOLUTION**

Use [`columns.data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) to set data source index for each column.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "responsive": true,
    "columns": [
        { "data": 5 },
        { "data": 4 },
        { "data": 3 },
        { "data": 0 },
        { "data": 1 },
        { "data": 2 }
    ]
} );
```

Don't forget to adjust table headings in `thead` section accordingly.

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/806/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: I'm sorry. I mean to change the index without changing the order. Whether it can be done?

Comment: @mosestoh, that is not possible. You can use [`name`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.name) if you don't want to use indexes but that is as far as you can get.

Comment: Thank you. I will make another right questions to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 3):

You could include the [**`ColReorder`**](http://cdn.datatables.net/#ColReorder) plugin and reorder the columns upon initialisation :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "responsive": true,
        colReorder: {
          order: [5,4,3,0,1,2]
        }
    } );
} );
```

forked fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/8qrqpjsp/

Comment: I'm sorry. I mean to change the index without changing the order. Whether it can be done?

Comment: @mosestoh, why do you need that? Sounds like a XY problem - guess you are out in a peculiar solution to solve a completely other issue ...?

Comment: Thank you. I will make another right questions to resolve my issue.