# Server side DataTables with Ignited-Datatables Library

Tags: jquery, datatables

How to Server side DataTables with Ignited-Datatables Library?

My application use CodeIgniter.

Library that I use is [Ignited-datatables Library](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/blob/master/application/libraries/Datatables.php).

My controller is like this :

```
public function get_book()
{
    $this->datatables->select('id, hotel, city, country, region')
                ->unset_column('id')
                ->from('hotel_book')
    echo $this->datatables->generate('json', '');
}
```

My HTML is like this:

```
                    <table id="example">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>                         
                            <th>Hotel</th>
                            <th>City</th>
                            <th>Country</th>
                            <th>Region</th>                                                   
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
```

My Javascript is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var table = $('#example').dataTable( {


                "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
                
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                    { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 3 ]},
                    { 'bSearchable': true }
                ],
                "Processing": true,
                "ServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": '<?php echo site_url(); ?>book/get_book',
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "iDisplayStart ":20,
                "oLanguage": {
                "sProcessing": "<img src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/ajax-loader_dark.gif'>"
                },      
                
                "columns": [
                        { "data": "hotel" },
                        { "data": "city" },
                        { "data": "country" },
                        { "data": "region" }
                ],  

                'fnServerData': function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback)
                {
                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        'dataType': 'json',
                        'type'    : 'POST',
                        'url'     : sSource,
                        'data'    : aoData,
                        'success' : fnCallback
                    });
                }
            } );
</script>
```

How to make searching, filter and paging into server side ?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to handle the searching, filter and paging in your server-side code. the parameters are already included in the datatables request. [https://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql](https://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql)

Comment: @markpsmith, Thank you for answering my question. Does it modify the  Ignited-Datatables Library? I still difficulties to implement the Codeigniter.

Comment: [check](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) this. I think it may help you. And one more thing i would like to mention, that use limit with the datatable 'length'  and 'start' request parameter. There is also a request parameter 'search[value]' and 'search[regex]' . I think the link is sufficient

Comment: And I completely handled the server side code by myself. I did not used any library. I have no knowledge about the "Ignited-Datatables Library"

Comment: @AbhisekMalakar, Thank you for answering my question. But, I still difficult to implement into my application. It's too difficult

Comment: The server side pagination and searching is already handled in the ignited datatable library. You don't need to write any additional script. Check the Datatables class for more info.

Answer (score 1):

There is error in your Code.

```
public function get_team()
{
    $this->load->library('Datatables');
    $this->datatables->select('*')
                ->unset_column('id')
                ->from('oric_team');
   echo $this->datatables->generate('json', '');

}
```

You are missing the Semi Colon before echo.
I am using your code and everything is working fine after putting semi colon.